# Xamarin: Setting and reading Notifications Permissions

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, permissions, xamarin.essentials

I am implementing LocalNotifications in my Xamarin app. My app is useless without those set. I need a X Platform way of reading and requesting the Notifications Permissions on my App for iOS and Android. I looked in Xamarin Essentials it is not in there.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: There are no permissions required for notifications on Android at this time (although I have heard that this might be changing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android, there is currently no need to set permissions to send notifications.

For iOS, the app must be registered with the system and the app must explicitly request permission before sending notifications to the users. You don't have to configure the info.plist or your iOS project, however [some approval levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#:%7E:text=Banner%20displays.,the%20app%20icon.) must first be requested and set for both local and remote notifications.

For more details, you can refer to the Apple Developer Documentation: [Asking Permission to Use Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications?language=objc)